# Get the text content of a wikipedia page given its title

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

When I give the title of a wikipedia page, I want the content of the page in pure text format. No images, no markup etc.

I have been going through the Wikipedia API, but couldn't find any relevant result.

Given, the simplicity of the task, I am sure this is supported the by the Wikipedia API.

So, how do I achieve this?

Comment: If you want just the text, you'll probably have to strip the markup yourself. I don't think MediaWiki will bother doing that for you, because the task is actually not that simple.

Comment: Stripping the markup is effectively impossible, since templates and parser functions generate a surprising amount of content. Stripping HTML, on the other hand, is quite doable.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function wiktext() {
    var title = prompt("Enter the title:","Title of Wikipedia Page to get");
    var address = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=txt&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=" + encodeURIComponent(title);
    $.get(address, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
wiktext();
</script>
```

Please note, however, that this is the Wikimarkup Text. And you need to strip off the first few lines that are headers describing the nested data structure.

You can then use [this Wiki to HTML parser by remy sharp](http://remysharp.com/2008/04/01/wiki-to-html-using-javascript/) to strip out most wiki stuff and give you some HTML. Then just simply use jquery's .text() method on an element you drop that HTML in to.

For more info see [the API doc here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?help)